# Javascript ES5: How to Group By a key and create Sub objects from a flat array of key-value objects without using Lodash or Underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-5

I have an array of Objects with 4 keys:

```
[
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "The hulk",
    "player_id": "10X2"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "SpiderMan",
    "player_id": "10X5"
  }
]
```

And I want to group my array by "Teams" such that it creates an array of Player objects for each team

```
 [
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "Players": [
      {
        "player": "Captain America",
        "player_id": "10X1"
      },
      {
        "player": "The hulk",
        "player_id": "10X2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "Players": [
      {
        "player": "Captain America",
        "player_id": "10X1"
      },
      {
        "player": "SpiderMan",
        "player_id": "10x5"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am currently trying to use reduce function from MDN prototype but it is not able to handle the sub object creation part.

Currently I have tried:

```
var group_to_values = result.reduce(function(obj, item) {
            obj[item.team] = obj[item.team] || [];
            obj[item.team].push({
                "team_profile_id":item.team_profile_id,
                "player":item.player,
                "player_id":item.player_id
            });
            return obj;
        }, {});
```

But it is not giving the desired result

Comment: `reduce` is all you need.  What have you tried?  Post some code

Comment: Updated the original question @Brandon

Comment: @apTNow You just need an `Object.values()` around that to create the array of arrays

Answer (score 1):

Since the result needs to be an array you can use it as the initial value for reduce instead of an object:

```js
var players = [
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "The hulk",
    "player_id": "10X2"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "SpiderMan",
    "player_id": "10X5"
  }
]

var teams = players.reduce(function (teams, player) {
  var matchingTeams = teams.filter(function(team) {
    return team.team === player.team;
  });
  var team;
  if (matchingTeams.length) {
    team = matchingTeams[0]
  } else {
    team = {}
    teams.push(team)
  }
  team.team = player.team;
  team.team_profile_id = player.team_profile_id;
  var teamPlayer = {
    player: player.player,
    player_id: player.player_id
  };
  team.players = team.players ? team.players.concat(teamPlayer) : [teamPlayer];
  return teams
}, [])

console.log(teams)
```

Answer (score 1):

While you iterate the players with `Array.reduce()`, destructure the player object, and separate between the player's properties, and team using spread.

If the `team` doesn't exist in the accumulator (`r`), create a new object with the team's properties, and the `Player: []` property. Push the players into the `Players` array of the relevant team. Use `Object.values()` to convert back to an array.

```js
const data = [{"team":"USA","team_profile_id":"10","player":"Captain America","player_id":"10X1"},{"team":"USA","team_profile_id":"10","player":"The hulk","player_id":"10X2"},{"team":"India","team_profile_id":"20","player":"Captain America","player_id":"10X1"},{"team":"India","team_profile_id":"20","player":"SpiderMan","player_id":"10X5"}]

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { team, team_profile_id, ...player }) => {
  if(!r[team]) r[team] = { team, team_profile_id, Players: [] }
  
  r[team].Players.push(player)

  return r
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

**How to ES5 this solution:**

- The main problem is `Object.values()`, but we can generate a `values()` functions using `Object.keys()`.
- Replace `const`s with `var`s, arrow functions with functions, destructuring with manual manual assignments.

```js
var data = [{"team":"USA","team_profile_id":"10","player":"Captain America","player_id":"10X1"},{"team":"USA","team_profile_id":"10","player":"The hulk","player_id":"10X2"},{"team":"India","team_profile_id":"20","player":"Captain America","player_id":"10X1"},{"team":"India","team_profile_id":"20","player":"SpiderMan","player_id":"10X5"}];

var result = values(data.reduce(function(r, o) {  
  var team = o.team;

  if(!r[team]) r[team] = {
    team: team,
    team_profile_id: o.team_profile_id,
    Players: [] 
  };
  
  r[team].Players.push({ player: o.player, player_id: o.player_id })

  return r
}, {}))

function values(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return obj[key];
  });
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could find the object and add the new player.

```js
var data = [{ team: "USA", team_profile_id: "10", player: "Captain America", player_id: "10X1" }, { team: "USA", team_profile_id: "10", player: "The hulk", player_id: "10X2" }, { team: "India", team_profile_id: "20", player: "Captain America", player_id: "10X1" }, { team: "India", team_profile_id: "20", player: "SpiderMan", player_id: "10X5" }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { team, team_profile_id, player, player_id }) => {
        var temp = r.find(q => q.team_profile_id === team_profile_id);
        if (!temp) r.push(temp = { team, team_profile_id, Players: [] });
        temp.Players.push({ player, player_id });
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do it but it works.

```js
const players = [
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "The hulk",
    "player_id": "10X2"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "SpiderMan",
    "player_id": "10X5"
  }
]

const teams = players.reduce((arr, player) => {
  let [team] = arr.filter(t => t.team === player.team)
  if (!team) {
    team = {
      team: player.team,
      team_profile_id: player.team_profile_id,
      Players: []
    }
    arr.push(team)
  }

  team.Players.push({
    player: player.player,
    player_id: player.player_id
  })
  
  return arr
}, [])

console.log(teams)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. First I create a set of unique team names and then filter the data based on that to get a list of relevant players:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "The hulk",
    "player_id": "10X2"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "SpiderMan",
    "player_id": "10X5"
  }
];

const res = [...new Set(data.map(e => e.team))]
    .map(teamName => ({ 
        team: teamName, 
        team_profile_id: data.find(e => e.team === teamName).team_profile_id,
        Players: data
            .filter(p => p.team === teamName)
            .map(p => ({ 
                player: p.player,
                player_id: p.player_id
                }))
            }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Our solutions are almost identical.

Comment: Even the wording at the beginning. Kindred spirits I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'use strict';

const inputData = [
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "USA",
    "team_profile_id": "10",
    "player": "The hulk",
    "player_id": "10X2"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "Captain America",
    "player_id": "10X1"
  },
  {
    "team": "India",
    "team_profile_id": "20",
    "player": "SpiderMan",
    "player_id": "10X5"
  }
];

function groupByTeams(data) {
  // Find the teams
  const teams = data.map(({ team }) => team);
  const uniqueTeams = [...new Set(teams)];

  // Map the array of unique values to return
  // desired result.
  return uniqueTeams.map(team => {
    return {
      team,
      team_profile_id: data.find((thisTeam) => thisTeam.team === team).team_profile_id,
      Players: data
        .filter(thisTeam => thisTeam.team === team)
        .map(({ player, player_id }) => ({ player_id, player }))
    }
  });
}

groupByTeams(inputData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
const playerData = [ ... ]
const teamGroups = playerData.reduce ((teamData, playerObj) => {
    const targetTeam = teamData.filter(t => t.team === playerObj.team)[0];

    if (!targetTeam) {
        return [ ...teamData, { 
            team: playerObj.team, 
            team_profile_id: playerObj.team_profile_id, 
            Players: [{ 
                player: playerObj.player, 
                player_id: playerObj.player_id 
            }] 
        }];
    }

    targetTeam.Players.push ({ player: playerObj.player, player_id: playerObj.player_id });
    return teamData;
}, []);
```